# Application Display Issue on iPhone X

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

The application built on MobileFirst (IBM worklight) is not displayed properly on iPhone X simulator.

How can we fix this display issue? 
Secondly, Mobilefirst compatible with "safe area" xCode 9 feature?

Please advice.

Comment: Please mention MFP version and the error you are getting . Also ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue and is being fixed. Open a PMR with IBM MobileFirst to obtain a fix. Until then , you can use this workaround:

Go to .html page of the application and replace the viewport meta tag by adding the `viewport-fit=cover property`

Replace

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,
minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
```

with new tag

```
<meta content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,viewport-fit=cover,
 maximum-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport">
```